# Folder permissions changing when running Ola Hallengren maintenance scripts

Tags: sql-server, backup, permissions, maintenance, ola-hallengren

We use a centralized backup location on a network share. Each instance uses the Ola Hallengren scripts to perform nightly backups.
I have a team that requires folder permissions to the same location where backups are stored. While the team has permissions to the parent folder it seems they no longer have permissions to any of the sub-folders where the backups are stored. I have narrowed it down to the command which executes the procedure dbo.xp_create_subdir. However, I am unable to figure out why the permissions are overwritten everytime this command is run.

How can I ensure the subfolder permissions are not being changed with the Ola Hallengren scrips?

Comment: My guess is that the Ola script is creating the subdir and not you or a member of the team, which would put whatever account created it as the owner.  You might need something to run after it to update the permissions on the folder or reassign ownership

Comment: I would also check the permission inheritence is in place within the folder structure on the remote location for the accounts that are losing their access.